# Disable file browser on form with a hidden input[type=file]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

We have a form that has an accordion.  One of the panels in the accordion which is collapsed has an `<input type="file">`  We are seeing cases where enter will trigger the file browser on on the hidden input field.

How can I disable the file browser when the input is on a hidden div.  Here is what I've tried but appears to be firing the browser first then running my stuff.

```
        $(window).keydown(function(event){
            if(event.keyCode == 13) {
                 if ($("input[type=file]").is(":hidden")) {
                    alert("HIDDEN")
                    event.preventDefault()
                    return false
                 } else {
                    alert("NOT HIDDEN")

                 };
            }
        });
```

Comment: Does setting `.attr('disabled', true)` do it?

Comment: File inputs are controlled by the browsers pretty strictly and weirdly in some cases.  It might be a better idea to instead of hiding the container, to simply not have it exist until you need it.  Append it to the dom on show call.

Comment: Hey @Barmer - Yes that works better but now it's disabled.  Can you make it a proper answer?

Comment: If you show the code you use to hide the DIV, I'll show how it can be modified to disable the input.

Comment: Make sure you get my name right, otherwise I won't be notified of your comment. Why don't you just let SO's username completion finish it for you?

Comment: when you disable it, set its `tabindex` property to `-1`. when you enable it, set it back to whatever it should be.

Comment: @Barmar I often encountered some issues using .attr("disabled",true) on IE8 and lower version... maybe .attr("disabled","disabled") is a more cross browser solution

Comment: @Franky I trust jQuery to do the cross-browser translation properly.

Comment: the proper way to use the disabled property is using the `.prop('disabled', 'disabled')` syntax. you remove the disabled property by doing `.removeProp('disabled')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure the catch would be on keydown.

But if you need a condition to see if the input is inside a hidden container, bootstrap 3 adds a `collapsed` class to the accordion element's header that is closed.. so look for it with Jquery. Something like:

```
if($("input[type=file]").parents(".panel").find(".panel-heading [data-toggle].collapsed").length > 0) {
    //Is closed
}
else {
    //Is opened
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
    $(window).keydown(function(event){
        if(event.keyCode == 13) {
             if ($("input[type=file]").is(":hidden")) {
                $("input[type=file]").attr("disabled","disabled");
                return false
             } else {
                $("input[type=file]").removeAttr("disabled");
             };
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

What's likely happening is that the user has tabbed into the element somehow. If that's the case, the solution then is simple - in addition to disabling/enabling the element, set its `tabindex` property like so:

Assuming `$(this)` is your file input element, when disabling:

```
var curTabIndex = $(this).prop('tabindex');
$(this)
    .attr('data-old-tab-index', curTabIndex)
    .prop({'disabled' : 'disabled', 'tabindex' : -1});
```

When enabling:

```
$(this).prop('tabindex', -1).removeProp('disabled');
```